# IllegalAccessError and PersistenceException while running Junit

Tags: java, jpa, junit

Recently facing IllegalAccessError and PersistenceException while running the DB dependent Junits which were earlier running fine. openjpa.jar is used for these tests.

Recent changes : Migration from XP to Win7

Please guide.

Comment: Not much to help with if you do not provide code or the exception stack trace.

Comment: Unable to access a field member of a class which is referred as idclass(JPA annotation) in another a class (say class A) from class A